# Opening different pages timed in a For-Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, window

it is me again with a strange question :) I would like to write a `for` loop which opens new windows with different lat and lng values. These are geocordinates. I have tried the code below. But it does not work and always opens `openWin(100,20)` I have no idea how I could possibly find a work around. Therefore every suggestion and proposal is welcome. Ideally I would also like to check all lng values from -180 to 180 as well in a second loop. But due to the fact the code below does not work I did not try to implement a second one.

```
function init() {
    var i = 2000;

    for(var lat=-90;lat<=90;lat+=10) {
        var lng = 20; // -180 --> 180
        setTimeout(function(){openWin(lat,lng);}, i);
        i+=2000;
        setTimeout(function(){closeWin();}, i);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `setTimeout()` runs sometime later, the value of `lat` will be that at the end of your `for` loop, not what you want it to be.

You can fix it with an IIFE closure that captures the value of the variable and holds it for use later in the `setTimeout()`:

```
function init() {
    var i = 2000;

    for(var lat=-90;lat<=90;lat+=10) {
        var lng = 20; // -180 --> 180
        (function(lat, lng) {
            setTimeout(function(){openWin(lat,lng);}, i);
            i+=2000;
            setTimeout(function(){closeWin();}, i);
        })(lat, lng);
    }
}
```

FYI, it isn't clear exactly  what you're trying to do with the `i` value.  I can't tell if you want that inside or outside the closure or when exactly you want it incremented.  It is also not clear how `closeWin()` knows which window to operate on.

Comment: @PhilippBraun - yes, the concept works no matter how many loops are outside the closure.  I already passed `lng` into the closure anticipating that you might be modifying that also.